# VBA auto add text, next to a specific word in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, autocomplete

I have been trying to do something theoretically simple, but I cant seem to finish it.

I want whenever a cell has a specific single "word", to auto add a specific "word2" next to it on the left (previous column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `Word` is in B1 and `Word2` is to go into A1

Put this into cell A1 (Row number will need to be amended to apply to differing rows):

```
=IF(B1="Word","Word2","")
```

Or in VBA:

```
For each oRow in Range("B1:B200")    

    If Range("B1").value2 = "Word" then
        Range("A1").value2 = "Word2"
    end if

next oRow
```

Just put this code into (or call it from) a `ThisWorkbook` event to allow it to run without manual input.